# Find the path beween two nodes even middle node is missing graph query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to find path between two nodes like

```
[:relation]    [:relation]     [:relation]
A-------------B--------------C------------D 
(name=A)   (name=B)      (name=C)   (name=D)
```

So, I have only A B D and want to find A B C D

I tried

```
MATCH 
  (q1:check4 {name:'A'})-[r1:relation]->
  (q2:check4 {name:'B'})-[r2:relation]->(q3:check4 {name:'D'})
RETURN DISTINCT q3.name as name
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to find the `name` attribute of the node between `B` and `D`, this query should do it:

```
MATCH 
  (:check4 {name:'A'})-[:relation]->
  (:check4 {name:'B'})-[:relation]->
  (q3:check4)-[:relation]->
  (:check4 {name:'D'})
RETURN DISTINCT q3.name as name
```

A tip: you do not have to name every node and relationship, e.g. `q1`, `r1` can be omitted.